# What is the meaning of [LS] and other symbols in Vim completion menu?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, plugin-coc, snippets

I installed `coc.nvim`, `vim-snippets` and `ultisnips` for my snippets in my Vim (gVim on Windows). I don't know the meaning of `[LS]` , `[B]` , `m`, `S` and `[S]` in this picture.

[image]

This picture shows part of my snippets in vim.

Comment: "Language Server"?

Comment: I think yes, it's related .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it provides you hint about the source of the suggestion:

- `[A]` the word is used in this buffer
- `[B]` the word is used in another buffer
- `[F]` the suggestion comes from the file system
- `[S]` the suggestion comes from the snippets list
- `[LS]` the suggestion is provided by the Language Server
- ...

You can get the full list of sources using the following command:

```
:CocList sources
```

More information in the Coc [documentation](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Completion-with-sources#completion-sources)

For Language Server suggestions you get an additional information about the type of the suggestion:

- `M` Module
- `S` Snippet
- `f` function
- `v` value
- `m` method
- ...

Comment: Thanks, your answer is perfect (: