# What is the arrow notation in the start of some lines in Vim?

Tags: gvim, plugin-coc

I was training in my Vim (gVim on Windows) that suddenly I saw this arrow notation ( `>>` ) in the start of some lines. When I oppend a javascript file, these appears to me. Do you know what are these and when they will show?

[image]

Some of them are green and some of them are red. But I don't know what is the meaning of these colors?
I think I installed a plugin and this is for that.

Comment: Could you tell us which version of Vim you are using (`:version`). Depending of the version you are using Coc can use some Vim functionalities to give more hints about these warning and errors.

Comment: VIM - Vi Imroved 9.0 ( 2022 Jun 28, compiled Jun 28 2022 13:9:53 ) MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are column signs set by Coc to highlight warnings or errors detected by the language server.

You can control their appearance using the `:CocConfig` command that let you edit the `~\vimfiles\coc-settings.json`:

```
{
    "diagnostic.errorSign": "⚡",
    "diagnostic.warningSign": "▲",
    "diagnostic.infoSign": "?",
    "diagnostic.hintSign": "!",
}
```

If you have the following settings in your `_vimrc`:

```
nmap <silent> [g <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap <silent> ]g <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next)
```

you can navigate the warnings and errors detected by the language server using the `]g`, `[g` key combination.

When you navigate through the diagnostic (you can also navigate with the cursor) you get hints about the diagnostics:

[image: Diagnostic Hint]

You can get also a list of all the diagnostic with the following commands:

```
:CocList diagnostics
```

[image: Coc Diagnostics]

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd like to highlight that vim calls these things "signs" so `:h sign` will give more information.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem completely.

Comment: How did you find out that it was CoC?

Comment: The same user has asked other questions [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/40371/23502) or [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/40338/23502) where he mentioned he is using Coc.